# Why does #define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE break these function pointers?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, shared-libraries, gnu

I have the following code in which the shared library being loaded is delivered as a pre-compiled binary. It is compiled with the linaro toolchain.

```
gbm_create_device(int fd)
{
   struct gbm_device *gbm = NULL;
   void *module;
   const struct gbm_backend *backend = NULL

   module = dlopen("/usr/lib/gbm/gbm_pvr.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
   backend = dlsym(module, "gbm_backend");
   gbm = backend->create_device(fd);

   gbm->surface_create(gbm, width, height, format, flags);
}

struct gbm_device {
   /* Hack to make a gbm_device detectable by its first element. */
   struct gbm_device *(*dummy)(int);

   int fd;
   const char *name;
   unsigned int refcount;
   struct stat stat;

   ...
   void (*bo_destroy)(struct gbm_bo *bo);

   struct gbm_surface *(*surface_create)(struct gbm_device *gbm,
                                         uint32_t width, uint32_t height,
                                         uint32_t format, uint32_t flags);
   struct gbm_bo *(*surface_lock_front_buffer)(struct gbm_surface *surface);
   ...
};
```

The code normally works correctly. However, when I add the following defines, `gbm->surface_create(...)` jumps to the wrong memory location in the shared library. Why? It is not apparent to me from the [official GNU page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

---

Additional Information:

I used gdb to check the first step after gbm->surface_create(...)`

Without these defines:

```
0xb6beb5d0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gbm/gbm_pvr.so
...
// Correct behavior
```

With the defines:

```
0xb6c414a4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gbm/gbm_pvr.so
...
// Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Can you add a gdb backtrace?

Comment: @yugr I can get that in a few hours (don't have access to the board right now), but I added some additional information from gdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct gbm_device` contains a `struct stat stat;` member.

`struct stat` changes size depending on `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`. It contains members `off_t st_size;` etc. that are 32-bit or 64-bit.

The struct in the binary compiled without `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and in your code compiled with `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` are not ABI-compatible.

The function pointers are located after that member of the structure; changing the size of that member changes the apparent offsets of the following members, which is how the wrong function pointer values are being used.